# ERROR: No matching distribution found for re

Tags: python, cpanel, python-module

I am trying to run a Python script on Cpanel using Python Application and when I add all module in a text file and run pip install I am getting this error.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement re 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for re [image]

Comment: only bs4 and requests go in this file. everything else is built-in

Comment: you dont need to add the default module in reuqirement.txt unless there is specific version requirement

Comment: @drum I have removed all of them except requests, bs4 and datetime. It accepted the DateTime module as well. Should I remove it?

Comment: depends. i dont know which library you are using, but from the looks of it, you should remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re` is Python's regex module, in fact, most of the modules listed there are python's built in modules. They don't need to be installed via pip and should be available automatically when you use `import` statements.

You can refer to built in modules here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: Yes, Just learned that by doing a quick search. Only three are installed. I had to remove the rest of them.